# Adding 0 count values in Counter, Python

Tags: python

I have written a snippet that fetches (**dates**)data from database and counts the occurrences of dates accordingly. However since the data in the Db is not consistent some of the dates are not present.My code is Below:

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

connection = MySQLdb.connect ()

cursor = connection.cursor ()

cursor.execute ()

#fetch all of the rows from the query
data = cursor.fetchall()
ddt =  sorted(set(data))

coll = Counter(data)
orddict = OrderedDict(sorted(coll.items()))# Sorts the dates in order
print orddict
```

The output is here:

[image]

Is there a way where I can get(print) the missing dates in between with count 0?

Edit 1 : I tried printing out a **datelist** in sequence however ,the code only prints today's date.The code is as follows:

```
def dert():
    d1 = date(2017, 07, 15)  # start date
    d2 = datetime.date.today()  # end date
    delta = d2 - d1         # timedelta 
    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        x = (d1 + timedelta(days= i))
    return  x 
print dert()
```

Comment: Are the dates somewhere? If they are not in your dict, not in your Counter and not in you db, what do you have that could allow recovering them?

Comment: Dates are present in the database ,but they are not consistent.

Comment: You need to give more details. I cannot infer what is going on with you telling me that dates are not consistent. Please provide more detail so I ca help you.

Comment: So in the database the dates are like 2017-10-06 , 2017-10-07 , 2017-10-09, 2017-10-11 , 2017-10-14.Thats why the counter doesn't show them,  I was asking for a way to include the missing dates with counter 0

Comment: Your DB is just a list of dates?

Comment: Dates along with other information,but I just need the dates column.

Comment: Why are you using `Counter` to do something your database can do in nearly less time?

Comment: wanted to implement it in python itself

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could create an additional list which will contain all dates in sequential order starting from the needed date/first date in db.

Now once you have the additional list you can run on the in checking for each if it is in the db, if in db print count, otherwise print 0

Comment: I tried doing that ,please check the edits in the question.